# How do write a parallel enumerated for loop in python when the function returns a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

This is the code I want to make parallel

```
dataset = {}
for index,Id in enumerate(MarketIds['Market Id']):
    dataset[index] = GetAllBidPrice(Id)
```

Comment: Do you mean that each loop iteration should be executed in a separate thread?

Comment: Check out the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module documentation.  It has a lot of important general information about parallelizing Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't care about the order that keys are inserted into the dictionary, a good option here would probably be the `imap_unordered` method of a [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) object.  Here's an example using all processor cores:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
p = Pool(None)  # can pass a specific number of cores
dataset = {idx: d for idx, d in p.imap_unordered(
           lambda idx, id: (idx, GetAllBidPrice(id)), 
           enumerate(MarketIds['Market Id']))}
```